# HTML isn't rendered before after translate3d transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm having a particular problem where the rendering of some HTML is delayed by a CSS3 transform3d animation. This happens on all browsers I've tested (Android 4.1 webview, iOS 7, Chrome for Mac, Safari for Mac).

I have a `<ul>` that acts as a container for my pages. Every `li` represents a page. The overflow property is set to hidden, so you can only see one page at a time.

When I want to transition to a new page, I set tranform3d to the correct value, and along with transition-duration property, it slides the new page into the view. The funny thing is, the new page isn't rendered before the transition is finished (so it slides in a white page, when the animation is done, the view is displayed).

I can see that the html is inserted before the transition, so it seems to be delaying the rendering of the new `<li>` element until after the transition is done.

I've also tried updateing the transform3d property 200ms after I insert the new `<li>` element, when I do this, the view is rendered halfway through the animation.

If I remove the transition-duration property, there is of course no animation, but the `<li>` element is rendered instantly.

Any way I can solve this? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/9RrAN/

Comment: You need to show us a demo and some code for us to be able to help

Comment: Alright, I'll try to recreate the problem in jsfiddle later tonight, and update my post.

Comment: @ZachSaucier: I've reproduced the problem. Link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You're right, the React code is a bit interesting... If you comment out the `translate3d` when the button is clicked and the comma in the line above, you can see how the ul's width is indeed expanding but the other elements remain hidden. This likely has to do with the way React deals with animations itself, I'd go post on whatever forums or bug requests they have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you were also animating the width at the same time as -webkit-transform, so the last `<li>` would wrap to the next line until the width reached its final value (which would happen as the transition ends). If I change the CSS to:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

then it works properly. Here's an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RrAN/2/)

(This is not related to React in any way.)